# Firebase Push - Key google.sent_time expected String but value was a java.lang.Long

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my Android application using `GCM Service` receives a `Firebase` push I get the following:

> W/Bundle: Key google.sent_time expected String but value was a
>   java.lang.Long.  The default value `<null>` was returned.

I know they are different services, but the application *is able to receive the push notification* and I can't find any information on the web about this error log.

Why am I getting this `java.lang.ClassCastException`?

---

### Complete Stacktrace

```
    11-10 10:51:33.536 31712-31712/abcd.com.abcd E/FirebaseInstanceId: Failed to resolve target intent service, skipping classname enforcement
    11-10 10:51:33.536 31712-31712/abcd.com.abcd E/FirebaseInstanceId: Error while delivering the message: ServiceIntent not found.
    11-10 10:51:33.546 31712-32529/abcd.com.abcd W/Bundle: Key google.sent_time expected String but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value <null> was returned.
    11-10 10:51:33.546 31712-32529/abcd.com.abcd W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
      java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
      at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:921)

      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.zza.zzae(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzo(Unknown Source)   
      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzn(Unknown Source)   
      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zzm(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService.zza(Unknown Source)    
      at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService$1.run(Unknown Source)                                              
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    11-10 10:51:33.546 31712-32529/abcd.com.abcd D/abcd: GCMBroadcastReceiver - Push received!
```

*Obs: "abcd" is replacing our package description.*

Comment: try to update libraries

Comment: but google highly recommends migration to FCM

Comment: Can you post the complete stacktrace? And have you tried actually using the corresponding FCM implementation and see if you still receive that error? And does the error occur randomly?

Comment: @AL. the error does not occur randomly. Using the corresponding FCM implementation wouldn't fire any exceptions at all. I will update my question with the complete stacktrace.

Comment: i have same issue but no solution please help is problem is solved